# counting channel discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
if (counterChannel && counterChannel.type === "GUILD_VOICE") {
    const currentName = counterChannel.name;
    const match = currentName.match(/^vouches-(\d+)$/);
    if (match) {
        const currentCount = parseInt(match[1]);
        const newCount = currentCount + 1;
        const newName = `vouches-${newCount}`;

        await counterChannel.setName(newName);
        console.log(`The counter channel's new name is ${newName}`);
    } else {
        console.error("Counter channel name format is invalid.");
    }
} else {
    console.error("Counter channel not found or is not a voice channel.");
}
```

I am making a Discord bot. It has a /vouch command and every time it is executed the counter should go up by one so for the counting system I am using a voice channel which should be renamed every time and the number should increase by one.

[image]

Yeah so it's just not quite working.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information on how your program is not working. Nevertheless, I will provide some avenues for you to explore to try to fix the issue.

Have you enabled the appropriate intents? You will need the `GUILDS` intent to update the voice channel. See [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents). You will also need to define your bot's permissions appropriately on the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and in your Discord server. In this case, you need to enable the `Manage Channels` permission for your bot (listed under the OAuth2 page) and then re-invite the bot to your Discord server.

Please also note that Discord has a rate limit of twice per ten minutes for renaming channels.